# Tikzpicture: Setting fill color does not work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am working with tikzpicture to plot a few data points.
I am trying to set the fill-color of my data points to something else than the default blue, but I don't see what I am doing wrong. 
I am sure I altered in the past the color by just changing the `fill` value, but it doesn't work in this case

I attached a MWE - can someone help me with this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}    
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\begin{document} 
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        nodes near coords,
        ylabel={time [s]},      
        enlargelimits=0.2,
        log basis y=10,
    ]
        \addplot+[
            black,
            fill=red,
            only marks,
            point meta=explicit symbolic,
            visualization depends on=\thisrow{alignment} \as \alignment,            
            every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny,anchor=\alignment}          
        ] 
        table [
           meta index=2
        ]{
             x         y       label  alignment
             0.4    7.24    C-1               0
             0.5    4.42    C-2               0
        };
    \end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Text}
    \label{fig:a1}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `mark options` instead of the options for the whole axis. You also don't need to load both `pgfplots` and `pgfplotstable`, and you should set your compatibility version of `pgfplots` with the `compat` option. You're also loading `amsmath` twice. In the future, please try to generate *minimal* examples, with all packages unnecessary to reproduce the problem removed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[
        nodes near coords,
        ylabel={time [s]},
        enlargelimits=0.2,
        log basis y=10,
    ]
        \addplot+[
            black,
            mark options={fill=red},
            only marks,
            point meta=explicit symbolic,
            visualization depends on=\thisrow{alignment} \as \alignment,
            every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny,anchor=\alignment}
        ]
        table [
           meta index=2
        ]{
             x         y       label  alignment
             0.4    7.24    C-1               0
             0.5    4.42    C-2               0
        };
    \end{semilogyaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Text}
    \label{fig:a1}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - one further question not directly related to this problem if I may - I use abbreviation/codes as C-1, C-2 etc. Is there a way to sneak in arbitrary many legend entries despite of having only 1 set of values? /addlegendentry{} would add only 1 entry as only 1 set of values is present (the red-circle). I want to piggy back the legend-system to provide a human readable version of my abbreviations. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use `\addlegendimage{empty legend}\addlegendentry{}` pairs... see page 217 of the v1.12 manual for more details. If you have other questions about that, its probably best to ask a new question :-)